# Normalized measures for curve slope similarity

Tags: correlation, similarities, intraclass-correlation

The website ["Spurious Correlations"](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations) lists many curves that have a similar shape and gives their correlation coefficient. Whilst the Pearson correlation $r$ measures whether deviations from their respective means are always in the same direction and is normalized to $-1\leq r \leq 1$, I wonder whether there are more sensitive measures for curve similarity. Specifically, two ideas came to my mind:

1. The intra class correlation *ICC(3,2)*, which measures whether the two curves (in ICC lingo "raters") agree at the same points (in ICC lingo *objects* to be rated).
2. The correlation between the derivatives, i.e. between $x'_i$ and $y'_i = y_{i+1} - y_i$, because it measures whether both curves in(de)crease at the same positions.

Are these established methods for measuring curve similarity, or are there other methods? Note that unbounded measures like the Frechet Distance are not of interest in this case, because they are only useful as a comparative measure when more than two curves are to be compared.